# Is there a predefined function for "(lambda **x: x)"

Tags: python

I found (lambda **x: x) is very useful for defining a dict in a succinct way, e.g.

```
xxx = (lambda **x: x)(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

Is there any pre-defined python function does that?

Comment: How about `dict`?

Answer (score 8):

The `dict` function/constructor can be used in the same manner.

```
>>> (lambda **x: x)(a=1, b=2, c=3) == dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
True
```

See `help(dict)` for more ways to instantiate `dict`s. You are not limited to just defining them with `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `{}` literal dictionary syntax. It is quite succinct. See [5.5. *Dictionaries*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in the **Data Structures tutorial**.

```
>>> xxx = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> xxx
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```